# function not deleting artist and song and code is not inserting artist, song in a table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need some help with my code.

I need to create a page that allows a user to add songs by artist name, album, year, etc.

The user should be able to delete a song added, my current issue is that when i add a song it does not add it to my table and upon clicking the delete button it does not delete the selected song upon refresh.

my clear all button works 100% but not my delete button.

Please can anyone help, will appreciate it

my JS/JSON code below:

```
//array that will be used to store user input
let art = [];

//will be used in the appendChild method
let body = document.getElementById("body");

function onLoad() {
let clear = document.getElementById("clear");
//create the clear all button
let clrbutton = document.createElement("button");
clrbutton.innerHTML = "Clear All";

 //EventListener will trigger if button is clicked
clrbutton.addEventListener("click", function clrAll() {
//clear the local storage
localStorage.clear();
});

//position the clear all button
clrbutton.style.display = "block";
clrbutton.style.marginTop = "5px";

// add button to HTML document
clear.appendChild(clrbutton);
}

//constructor function [property, value]
function Artist(song, artist, album, release_date, genre) {
this.song = song;
this.artist = artist;
this.album = album;
this.release_date = release_date;
this.genre = genre;
}

//function to get user input values
function addArtist() {
let newArtist = new Artist(
document.getElementById("song").Value,
document.getElementById("artist").value,
document.getElementById("album").value,
document.getElementById("year").value,
document.getElementById("genre").value
);
//push new data to the back of the array
 art.push(newArtist);
//add songData property to localstorage
localStorage.songData = JSON.stringify(art);
}

//check if localStorage contains any data, if true, theres's already stored data in localStorage
if (localStorage.songData) {
//Songdata
art = JSON.parse(localStorage.songData);

 console.log(art);
//the in keyword, loops through each key to the art array
for (let i in art) {
//creating a table row for each object in the art array
let table_row = document.createElement("tr");
//create a button to delete a song
let dltbutton = document.createElement("button");
dltbutton.innerHTML = "Delete"
//EventListener will trigger when clicked
dltbutton.addEventListener("click", function dltSong() {
//splice(i) will delete the selected song
art.splice(i, 1);
localStorage.SongData = JSON.stringify(art);
});
//within each object, [key, value] = placeholder varibles, i refers to the specific object in the array
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(art[i])) {
//create a th tag for eahc value in the object, within the art array
let div = document.createElement("th");
//data in th is now editable
div.contentEditable = "true";
//value = the value of each property in the object
div.innerHTML = value;
//when there is a change in the data in the input element, thee below function is called
div.oninput = function (e) {
//change the value of the key affected
art(i)[key] = e.target.innerText;
localStorage.songData = JSON.stringify(art);
};
//styling our table
div.style.margin = "10%";
div.style.border = "1 px solid black";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.style.padding = "10px";

table_row.appendChild(div);
}

body.appendChild(table_row);
body.appendChild(dltbutton);
}
```

}

My html:

```
<!--Add load function-->
<body id="body" onload="onLoad()">
 <h1>Music store</h1>

<form>
<!--Enter song name-->
<label>Enter song name:</label>
<input type="text" name="song" id="song" required />
<!--Enter artist name-->
<label>Enter artist name:</label>
<input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" required />
<!--Enter album name-->
<label>Enter album's name:</label>
<input type="text" name="album" id="album" required />
<!--Enter release date-->
<label>Release date:</label>
<input type="text" name="year" id="year" required />
<!--Enter genre-->
<label>Choose a genre:</label>
<select id="genre">
<option value="">..Choose a option..</option>
<option value="Pop">Pop</option>
<option value="Rock">Rock</option>
<option value="Hip-Hop">Hip-Hop</option>
<option value="Metal">Metal</option>
<option value="Blues">Blues</option>
<option value="Alt">Alt</option>
</select>
<!--Our submit button-->
<button onclick="addArtist()">Add song</button>
</form>
<div>
<!--Info to help user navigate-->
<!--edit song info-->
<h4>Songs listed here can be edited and will be saved upon change.</h4>

<!--Delete song info-->
 <h4>To remove a song from the list, click on the delete button. The song will be removed once page is refreshed</h4>
<!--Clear all info-->
  <!--add an id to the h4 tag to position the clear all button-->
<h4 id="clear"> To clear all songs on the page, click the Clear All button. The songs will be cleared once page is refreshed</h4>

</div>

<!--Script to load javascript file-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="music.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does render html based on your data only once (onload). You don't get to see the changes unless you manually take care of rerendering your DOM. You are changing your data (model), but the view does not update.

You get this functionality in a lot of JS reactive frameworks (Vue, Angular, React) but it's not a standard Javascript thing.

Edit: the easiest what you could do is take everything what you have in the for loop and put it in a separate function. Add in the begin of the function a piece of code that removes existng DOM elements so that you don't get duplicates. Then call this new render function on each change of the array. You'll probably run into some issues with this (scroll not being preserved for example) but this is a good begin and a really small change.